# Quickly fill large Numpy matrix from Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy

I have DataFrame `df` with info of x-axes, y-axes, and values to fill numpy matrix `mat`.

Example of smaller `df`:

```
y   x   x   x   x   value   value   value   value
1   6   3   6   4   100     10      300     15
1   6   2   8   7   50      200     35      70
5   7   5   4   6   2       50      40      400
7   5   3   2   1   105     80      35      44
```

I want to fill `mat = np.zeros(shape=(10,10))` by each `y` is row index, `x` is column index with the value at the same position as `x` in value block. Such as

```
col=1, row=6, value=100 ###
col=1, row=3, value=10
col=1, row=6, value=300 ###
col=1, row=4, value=10
col=1, row=6, value=50  ###
```

If more than one value goes into that position (like `###`), do average. Is there any ways to go direct from Pandas to matrix (or other quick way)?

What I can do now is using `np.ravel` of selected column in dataframe first to make 1D-arrays and fill from those arrays but it is slow and redundant a lot.

Comment: Are the number of `x` columns fixed and known?

Comment: @R.S.NikhilKrishna yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct row and column indices and perform slice assignment.

```
val = df.values
j = val[:, 0].repeat(4)
i = val[:, 1: 5].ravel()
v = val[:, 5:].ravel()
mat = np.zeros(shape=(10,10), dtype=int)

mat[i, j] = v

mat

array([[  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  44,   0,   0],
       [  0, 200,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  35,   0,   0],
       [  0,  10,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  80,   0,   0],
       [  0,  15,   0,   0,   0,  40,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  50,   0, 105,   0,   0],
       [  0,  50,   0,   0,   0, 400,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,  70,   0,   0,   0,   2,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,  35,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]])
```

---

For averages

```
val = df.values
j = val[:, 0].repeat(4)
i = val[:, 1: 5].ravel()
v = val[:, 5:].ravel()

sums = np.bincount(i * 10 + j, v, 100)
cnts = np.bincount(i * 10 + j, minlength=100)
mask = cnts > 0

sums[mask] /= cnts[mask]

print(sums.reshape(10, 10))

[[   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
 [   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.   44.    0.    0.]
 [   0.  200.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.   35.    0.    0.]
 [   0.   10.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.   80.    0.    0.]
 [   0.   15.    0.    0.    0.   40.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
 [   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.   50.    0.  105.    0.    0.]
 [   0.  150.    0.    0.    0.  400.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
 [   0.   70.    0.    0.    0.    2.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
 [   0.   35.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
 [   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]]
```

Comment: Any suggestion for averaging?

Comment: Do you mind explain a bit about `np.bincount` here? I now read the document but not really understand what's going on.

Comment: `np.bincount` will count the number of times each index (or bin) is encountered.  The real trick is how I used `i * 10 + j` to turn row and column indices into the indices of a flattened array... then used `np.bincount`.  Ok, so that explains the counting.  Secondly, I perform another `np.bincount` but this time with `weights`.  This uses the array I passed as `weights` to sum up instead of counting.  This acts as the sum within each bin.  When I divide the two, I get an average.  I had to use a `mask` to ensure I didn't divide by zero.

Comment: Almost got it. Sry for taking a bit time. If my matrix is `m*n`, should `i * 10` change to be `i * m` or `i * n`? Or `10` comes from something else?